# Easiest way to solve lower hessenberg matrix with Gaussian Elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination, toeplitz-matrices

This question has been asked before, but in this case, we should do a little bit different thing.

Assume that we have this lower Hessenberg matrix.

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
CB & 0 &0  & 0 & 0\\ 
CAB & CB &  0& 0 &0 \\ 
CA^2B &CAB  & CB & 0 & 0\\ 
CA^3B & CA^2B &CAB  & CB & 0\\ 
CA^4B & CA^3B & CA^2B & CAB & CB 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $CB \in \Re^{n x n}$ and $CA^iB \in \Re^{n x n}$ and $n = 1$

We want to solve $Ax = b$, classic. But what if we have $n > 1$ ? E.g matrix $A$ looks like this:

```
     0.07741     0.23210     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
     0.23865   123.33000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
     0.12238    29.62902     0.07741     0.23210     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
    -0.00611    15.82693     0.23865   123.33000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
     0.10198    28.81903     0.12238    29.62902     0.07741     0.23210     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
    -0.05920   -12.09672    -0.00611    15.82693     0.23865   123.33000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
     0.07206    21.47042     0.10198    28.81903     0.12238    29.62902     0.07741     0.23210     0.00000     0.00000
    -0.05632   -15.31863    -0.05920   -12.09672    -0.00611    15.82693     0.23865   123.33000     0.00000     0.00000
     0.04746    14.49060     0.07206    21.47042     0.10198    28.81903     0.12238    29.62902     0.07741     0.23210
    -0.04167   -12.22749    -0.05632   -15.31863    -0.05920   -12.09672    -0.00611    15.82693     0.23865   123.33000
```

Here we can see that the dimension and column dimension is $n=2$. Solving if $n=1$ is easy. Then I use Gaussian Elimination.

But how should I do in this case when $n > 1$ and $A$ is still lower traingular hessenbeg matrix? What is the easiest way in this case when $n > 1$?

Comment: forward substitution http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/BackSubstitutionMod.html

Comment: Yes, but as you see, there is a little bit of a gap (zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a system like this you can use forward substitution, $Ax=b$ then

$$x_{1} = \frac{b_{1}}{a_{1,1}} $$

and

$$ x_{i} = \frac{b_{i} - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{i,j} x_{j} }{ a_{i,i} }$$

Comment: Yes, I know that. But how about the diagonal zeros?

Comment: Where do you have zeros on the diagonal? It looks like the diagonal is a bunch of matrices? Also, why are you using Fraktur characters?

Comment: Assume that we need to turn `0.23210` to zero. Then we can multiply 0.23210 with 123.33000/0.23210 and the whole row too. But then what? I need to find a number for 0.07741 to turn it to zero.

Comment: Else I need to swap the rows right?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I imagine but I'm not sure there is some analytical solution. The matrix is lower hessenberg.

Comment: Yes! Perhaps I should change the question due to that name.

Comment: You think I need to solve it with least squares?

Comment: I think there is some fast way to solve toeplitz matrices with the fourier transform but I don't know much about it.

Comment: I have solve this problem if the matrix was a toeplitz matrix. But now it's a hessenberg matrix.

Comment: Like this $x = (A^T A)^{-1}A^T b $ ?

Comment: Is the matrix full rank?

Comment: yes. It has full rank.